# Finding item based on sibling before or after

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, traversal

Let's say I have a set of data like this:

```
var nodes = [
  {
    type: 'pants',
  },
  {
    type: 'glasses',
  },
  {
    type: 'jacket'
  },
  {
    type: 'pants'
  }
]
```

I'm looking for a way to `find` (return item) and `map` (modify item in place) the item where `type` is `pants` and the preceding node has `type` equal to `jacket`. So it should only return (or modify) the last item in this array.

Is there any way to do this in javascript? Are their any libraries that allow this functionality?

Comment: I think this is too weird to have a built in method for. Just loop the array `length-1` times, comparing `[i].type to [i+1].type`, modify `[i+1]` if your case is met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for could do it:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length - 1; i++) {
  if (nodes[i + 1].type == "pants" && nodes[i].type == "jacket") {
    // change or modify
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a function using reduce method:

```js
var nodes = [
  {
    type: 'pants',
  },
  {
    type: 'glasses',
  },
  {
    type: 'jacket'
  },
  {
    type: 'pants'
  }
]
function test(arr,el,bef){
  return arr.reduce(function(acc,a,i,arr){
        if(a.type==el && arr[i - 1] && arr[i-1].type==bef){
         acc.push(a); 
        }
        return acc ;
    },[])
}
console.log( test(nodes,'pants','jacket'))
```